# difference between Tensorflow's Graph and GraphDef

Tags: tensorflow

I'm quite new to the tensorflow. I would like to understand to conceptual difference between Graph and GraphDef.

furthermore, which one should I have to run a graph loaded from protobuf file (.pb)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Graph` or `Computional Graph` is the core concept of tensorflow to present computation. When you use tensorflow, you firstly create you own `Computation Graph` and pass the `Graph` to tensorflow. How to do that? As you may know, tensorflow support many front-end programming languages, like Python, C++, Java and Go and the core language is C++; how do the other languages transform the `Graph` to C++? They use a tool called `protobuf` which can generate specific language stubs, that's where the `GraphDef` come from. It's a serialized version of `Graph`.

> which one should I have to run a graph loaded from protobuf file (.pb)

You should read your `*pb` file using `GraphDef` and `bind` the `GraphDef` to a (default) `Graph`, then use a session to run the `Graph` for computation, like the [following code](https://gist.github.com/jubjamie/2eec49ca1e4f58c5310d72918d991ef6):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename ='PATH_TO_PB.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
LOGDIR='/logs/tests/1/'
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Comment: how do i test the network after i load the pb file ? where is my network ?

Answer (score 3):

GraphDef is the proto defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto). This is the serialized version of graph. You can print, store, or restore a GraphDef in any TensorFlow frontend (Python, R, C++, Java, ...). When it is stored to a file, usually the file name ends with `.pb`, so you should use GraphDef for `.pb` files.

Graph is an abstract concept, which can be in different forms for different frontends. For Python, tf.Graph() would return an Python object ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3935)) that contains the GraphDef and many utilities.

For python, you can load a GraphDef using [tf.import_graph_def](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def). Here is a simple code example:

```
  with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_def_pb_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    ...
```