# How to change the input to an OP in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to change the intput to a tesor after it was constructed. Take the following simplified example: `x` `(constant=42.0)`, `s` `(x^2)`, and `x_new` `(constant=4.0)`.

I want to change the input to `s` from being `x` to being `x_new`. After performing this operation I expect `s.eval() == 16.0`

```
x = tf.constant(42.0, name='x')
s = tf.square(x, name='s')
x_new = tf.constant(4.0, name='x_new')

tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()

Out[6]: 
node {
  name: "x"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 42.0
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "s"
  op: "Square"
  input: "x"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "x_new"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        tensor_shape {
        }
        float_val: 4.0
      }
    }
  }
}
versions {
  producer: 24
}
```

I've tried using `tf.contrib.graph_editor.reroute_inputs`, but for the life of me I can't figure out what to do with the subgraphs it returns.

I've also tried playing with `tf.import_graph_def` as vaguely described in this git issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1758), but no matter how many ways I try to do it, I don't get `s` to change intputs from `x` to `x_new`.

Anyone know how to use either of these approaches to accomplish this trivial example?

Answer (score 1):

So this is something I run into regularly when trying to use pre-trained networks. As you mentioned in your question, one approach is to "import_graph_def" as described in the [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1758). Google keeps pointing me here and the issue lacks a clean example, so I'll post a minimal solution here.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant(42.0, name="x")
    s = tf.square(x, name="s")
    print(sess.run(s))
    scope = "test"
    x_new = tf.constant(4.0, name="{}/x".format(scope))
    tf.import_graph_def(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), name=scope, input_map={'x': x_new})
    print(sess.run("{}/s:0".format(scope)))
```

Note that if you do not provide a scope, the default is "import" as per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/import_graph_def).

If instead you need to persist a graph and then edit it (or load a persisted graph from someone else) you can save the graph and reload it (based off of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059848/difference-between-tensorflows-graph-and-graphdef))

```
import tensorflow as tf

scope = "test"
graph_filename = "test.pb"

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant(42.0, name="x")
    s = tf.square(x, name="s")
    print(sess.run(s))
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().SerializeToString())

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    x_new = tf.constant(4.0, name="{}/x".format(scope))
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        bytes_read = graph_def.ParseFromString(infile.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name=scope, input_map={'x': x_new})
    print(sess.run("{}/s:0".format(scope)))
```

@Moshe asked in the comments about working with import_meta_graph so I'll add a quick example. If you want to do the replacement on import_meta_graph (in my opinion this is best as you skip all of import/exporting) then use method 1. Otherwise use method 2 (import/export trick) to programmatically add inputs.

Export example (note that for such a simple example we need to create at least one variable to avoid Saver from throwing exceptions):

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    scope = "test"
    model_name = 'my-model'
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        #Create a toy network
        x = tf.constant(42.0, name="x")
        s = tf.square(x, name="s")
        print(sess.run(s))
        #Save the network
        w = tf.Variable(2.0, name="w") #Need at least one variable to make saver happy
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #Need to initialize variables before saving
        saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
        tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection('s', s) #Select the network pieces to save
        saver.save(sess, model_name)
```

Import example (uncomment lines marked with method 2 to create dynamic inputs):

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    scope = "test"
    model_name = 'my-model'
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        x_new = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="{}/x".format(scope))
        saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(model_name), import_scope=scope, input_map={'x': x_new}) #Method 1
        # saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(model_name)) #Method 2
        saver.restore(sess, model_name)
        # tf.import_graph_def(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), name=scope, input_map={'x': x_new}) #Method 2
        s = tf.compat.v1.get_collection('s')[0]
        for i in range(4):
            print(sess.run("{}/s:0".format(scope), {"{}/x:0".format(scope): i}))
```

Comment: You can also load/save meta graphs using import_scoped_meta_graph/export_scoped_meta_graph from the tensorflow.python.framework.metagraph package. Combined with functions such as remove_training_nodes, extract_sub_graph, and convert_variables_to_constants from the tf.graph_util package, this can be very useful for performing edits on an existing graph.

Comment: do you know a way to change the input of the placeholder AFTER it was imported using import_meta_graph? I need to do it in a loop inside map_fn, and can't find a way to do it

Comment: Hopefully, I've answered your question. Also if anyone from Google reads this, the Tensorflow documentation is really impossible to make sense of.

Comment: @Moshe, if this does answer your question could you upvote the answer :)

Comment: Nope, the second method does not work as the tf.import_graph seems to import only the graph without the weights and I get an error about using uninitialized variables. What does work is freezing the graph as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394332/tensorflow-applying-an-imported-graph-operation-to-each-element-of-2d-tensor/57397780#57397780

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer. I've also tried messing around with graph editor, but to no avail. I've tried to manually change the input list of the following operation (in this case s):

```
x = tf.constant(42.0, name='x')
s = tf.square(x, name='s')
x_new = tf.constant(4.0, name='x_new')

s.inputs._inputs[0] = x_new

#if you want to get all operations consuming x...
outputConsumers = tf.contrib.graph_editor.get_consuming_ops([x])
```

but this invokes no change on execution and there seems to be other bookkeeping involved.

Have you gotten any closer?

**EDIT**

I wouldn't encourage using this in production code, but the python tensorflow wrapper code for operations has this built in function that seems to get the job done.

```
def _update_input(self, index, tensor):
    """Update the input to this operation at the given index.
    NOTE: This is for TF internal use only. Please don't use it.
```

Comment: Please provide a comment if you dont have the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use a placeholder instead of a constant.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
s = tf.square(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(s.eval({x: 5}))
  print(s.eval({x: 4}))
```

Comment: In this simplified example, certainly, but I am importing an existing model and combining that with another model that I'm working on. It's a pretty ugly hack to try to go manipulate the other model to change its expected input to come from my input pipeline instead of the input pipeline it was originally built for. That's why I need to actually change the input to the OP after-the-fact, rather than alter the code of the original model.