# Tensorflow: applying an imported graph operation to each element of 2d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are questions answering parts of my question but I can't connect the pieces together.
Suppose I have a graph that operates on a 1d array of just 2 elements

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2], name="input")
```

I want to build a graph that can receive an arbitrary long 2d array of such elements and run the first graph on it

```
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name = 'x')
```

I know how to import the first graph (tf.import_graph_def) and how to run some operation on an array using `tf.map_fn`. But how can I combine the two?
For each run of the network I need to pass it a different input. But the mapping is done inside tf.import_graph_def. Should I do the import each time in the function called in the loop? Sounds wrong ...

The code below works, but I believe there is a better way:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_1:
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2], name="input")
y = tf.add(input[0], input[1])
output = tf.identity(y, name="output")

gdef_1 = g_1.as_graph_def()

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_combined:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name = 'x')

    def calc_z(el):
        y, = tf.import_graph_def(gdef_1, input_map={"input:0": el},
                               return_elements=["output:0"])
        return y

    final_result = tf.map_fn(calc_z, x)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(graph=g_combined) as sess:
    # For tensorboard
    # run it as tensorboard --logdir=graphs
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)
    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([final_result], feed_dict = {x:[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}))
    writer.close()
```

Update: I tried to achieve the same result, but to keep the imported graph trainable, but fail to do so.
The return_elements argument to `import_meta_graph` seems to be just ignored and only the saver is returned. Then a call to restore fails with the error

> Tensor Tensor("map/while/save/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string) may not be fed
>   I'm using the code below:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
xx = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2], name="xx")
yy = tf.add(xx[0], xx[1])
yy = tf.identity(yy, name = 'yy')
#need at least 1 varaible to save the graph
_ = tf.Variable(initial_value='fake_variable')

config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:    
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    saver.save(sess, "./model_ex2")

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name = 'x')

    def calc_z(el):
#         saver, yy  = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./model_ex2.meta", 
#                                            input_map={"xx:0": el}, return_elements=["yy:0"])
#         saver.restore(sess, "./model_ex2")
#         return yy
        # return_elements argument seems to be ignored and only the saver is returned.
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./model_ex2.meta", 
                                           input_map={"xx:0": el})
        saver.restore(sess, "./model_ex2")
        return yy

    final_result = tf.map_fn(calc_z, x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([final_result, op], feed_dict = {x:[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}))
```

Comment: I think your current code is perfectly good. You will not be reimporting the graph once per element in `x`, `calc_z` is only actually called once, `gdef_1` is imported once and it is wired up within `g_combined` so each iteration within `tf.map_fn` uses that imported graph. Note that `tf.import_graph_def` is not actually a TensorFlow in-graph operation.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, my problem involves a meta graph, which is pre-trained. I tried to call import_meta_graph inside the map function, but this does not work. What should I do? (maybe post a separate question?)

Comment: It is a different case, but going through the source code I think it should work the same (with the difference that `import_meta_graph` will return you a pair with the saver and the `return_elements` tensors)... You could also import the meta graph in a separate graph, freeze it and then import the frozen graphdef as you are doing now, but then the imported one would not be trainable anymore. Please give more details of what is the issue that you are facing with `import_meta_graph`, here or in another question, as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Freezing and importing seems to work, I'm verifying it! If you wish, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution is actually good already. The graph is imported only once when `g_combined` is constructed, not once per element in `x`, so it does what you would like to.

If you have a metagraph instead, it should work similarly with [`tf.train.import_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph), since `input_map` and `return_elements` should also be usable with it (note however this functions returns the imported saver too). However, you can also import the metagraph in a different graph, freeze it (e.g. using [`tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants)) and then import that graph def into the final graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf

meta_graph_path = ...
meta_graph_save_path = ...
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_meta_import, tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_path)
    saver.restore(sess, meta_graph_save_path)
    frozen_graph = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), 'output')

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_combined:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name = 'x')
    def calc_z(el):
        y, = tf.import_graph_def(frozen_graph, input_map={'input:0': el},
                                 return_elements=['output:0'])
        return y
    final_result = tf.map_fn(calc_z, x)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

The only catch of this solution is that it the imported part will obviously be frozen and not trainable.

Comment: Now I realized that there are cases I need the imported graph to be trainable.I tried your idea of using import_meta_graph but fail.First, the return_elements argument seems to be not processed (I'm using v 1.15) and only the saver is returned. Then the restore fails with an error "Tensor("map/while/save/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string) may not be fed". I posted the code in the body of the question

Comment: @MosheKravchik Mmm I'm not sure where that errors come from tbh. A couple of thoughts anyway. If `return_elements` doesn't work with `import_meta_graph`, you should still be able to retrieve the tensors with something like `tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('yy').outputs[0]` (or maybe `'import/yy'`, I'm not sure if that was the default if you didn't specify a scope). About restoring, it doesn't really make sense to do `saver.restore` in one session, then finalize that session and open a new one. I'd call `restore` only on the second session that you are actually using.

Comment: @MosheKravchik About the error, not sure if this make sense, but have you tried to pass `import_scope=''` to `import_meta_graph`? I'm not sure if it adds some prefix to the imported op names by default, which would cause the saver to not find the variables (I don't think this is the error but just in case).

Comment: It is indeed possible to get `yy`. I moved the restore to the second session, unfortunately it does not make any difference, I still get the `Tensor Tensor("map/while/save/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string) may not be fed` error :-(

Comment: @MosheKravchik Sorry, I don't know what may be the reason for that error, maybe try posting a new question in case someone else may help you with that...