# How to use a frozen.pb file for testing ?

Tags: tensorflow

I have  :
x_test data (1061 * 88 ) 88 is the length of feature vector and
y_test (1061 * 6) labels, 6 is the length of vector(one hot vector) i.e({0,0,1,0,0,0})
and a frozen file (frozen.pb)

Comment: I extracted the graph from the frozen file using this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48318045/5695391] and after this, I found my input and output tensor but dont know how to proceed to find accuracy !

Comment: If your old graph has accuracy, then extract it and then do `out = sess.run(acc, feed_dict={x: ..., y:..})`